How to Set a Full-Screen Splash Screen in .NET MAUI Blazor App for Android
I'm working on a .NET MAUI Blazor application and I am having trouble setting a full-screen splash screen for Android. Despite my efforts, the splash screen does not cover the entire screen as intended.
Here's what I've tried so far:
svg and png images
1.
2.
3.
the splash screen does not display in full screen on devices running Android 12+. Is there a known issue or an additional configuration required for this to work in .NET MAUI on newer versions of Android?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Short answer:
Starting with Android 12.0 or higher versions, the splash screen icon will be displayed inside a circular frame and everything outside that frame will be hidden by a mask. So you can't set full image splash screen. For more details, please refer to Splash screens.
